# Why some Windows process stay writing on disk even on system idle?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive

Today I watched my "[Windows Resource Monitor](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/closer-windows-resource-monitor/)" for some time and noticed that even when my system was on idle state( I was not running anything more beyond just Windows) there are some processes, such as "System" that keep writing on my hard disk. I took a picture of it (it is on Portuguese):

[image]

Why does this happen? Before seeing it I thought that there was no HDD activity when Windows is idle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be log files that are being written to the disk, or the page file could be swapping in and out a little.

In short, just because you consider a state idle, does not mean that nothing is happening. Things are happening all the time, and sometimes that means that writes are happening.